# Storyboard Preparing for Seque+Passing over data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, uilabel, uistoryboard

I have a detail view controller that is hooked up to a table view cell. I have a data model. It is an `NSObject` and has a `NSMutableArray` will all my properties I need in them.

I hooked up a label to an `@property` and named it `questionLabel`. For some reason, when I push over to the detail view, it does not display the question I put in the data model for the `NSMutableArray`.

At first I thought the segue was not working, but when I tried to change the navigation bar title, it worked when I passed my data from my `NSMutableArray`.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong with my label?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushDetail"])
    {
        // Create an instance of our DetailViewController
        DetailQuestionViewController *DQV = [[DetailQuestionViewController alloc] init];

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        // Setting DQV to the destinationViewController of the seque
        DQV = [segue destinationViewController];

        Question *selectedQuestion = [self.myQuestionList questionAtIndex:path.row];

        DQV.questionLabel.text = [selectedQuestion questionName];
        DQV.navigationItem.title = [selectedQuestion questionRowName];



    }


}
```

---

## UPDATE (For: adambinsz)

### Table view

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushDetail"])
    {
        // Create an instance of our DetailViewController
        DetailQuestionViewController *DQV = [[DetailQuestionViewController alloc] init];

        // Setting DQV to the destinationViewController of the seque
        DQV = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Question *selectedQuestion = [self.myQuestionList questionAtIndex:path.row];

        DQV.detailItem = selectedQuestion;



    }


}
```

### detailView

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        Question *theQuestion = (Question *)self.detailItem;
        self.questionLabel.text = theQuestion.questionName;

        NSLog(@"The Question's questionName is %@", theQuestion.questionName);

     }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

The reason I think it may not be working, is because the if statement for `self.detailItem` is not checking it correctly.

The method gets called just not the `detailItem`.

Comment: What's the need for the custom setter method for detailItem? Why not just create a Question variable on DetailQuestionViewController then set that in `prepareForSegue`? This should be very simple, I think you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: Could you please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to my original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label probably hasn't been created yet when you try to set its text. I would create a `selectedQuestion` instance variable on `DetailQuestionViewController` and set it when you create the view controller. Something like this:

```
// Create an instance of our DetailViewController
DetailQuestionViewController *DQV = [[DetailQuestionViewController alloc] init];

NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

// Setting DQV to the destinationViewController of the seque
DQV = [segue destinationViewController];

DQV.selectedQuestion = [self.myQuestionList questionAtIndex:path.row];
```

And in DetailQuestionViewController's `viewDidLoad` method, set your label's text by using:

```
self.questionLabel.text = [selectedQuestion questionName];
self.navigationItem.title = [selectedQuestion questionRowName];
```

Comment: No. It still doesn't work for me. Now, not even the navigationItem title shows up.

Comment: Can you post what your code looks like now? Also, make sure that `[selectedQuestion questionName]` is returning a valid NSString.

Comment: I think I might be doing the instance variable incorrectly. Do you want me to declare it like this? '@property (strong, nonatomic) id selectedQuestion;'

Comment: It should be `@property (nonatomic, strong) Question *selectedQuestion;`, and you also need to add `#import "Question.h"`(or whatever the name of your Question class file is) to the top of `DetailQuestionViewController.h`.

Comment: Sorry, it still does not work. I fixed it to say what you said, but still same result.

Comment: Did you also add `@synthesize selectedQuestion` to `DetailQuestionViewController.m`?

Comment: I know what the problem is. Selected question is not a valid NSString. It is returning null when I do an NSLOG. Yes I did the @synthesize. Does that info help?

Comment: It sounds like the `questionName` of `selectedQuestion` isn't being set correctly. Sorry, but I can't help you any further without more detail.

Comment: Ok. Listen for a second. I just did something in the DetailView, and now the label appears with info, but not for the right question I clicked on. I guess the indexpath.row is wrong. If I show you that code, can you please help me?

Comment: Okay hold on, let me just pasted it in the question